# Are all the Drawable Re-sizers online free to use without acknolwedgement

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making an app in Android Studio, and I want to add an ImageButton but realized I need multiple copies of the images like xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, etc.

I came across a few solutions to generate them for me, like https://github.com/delight-im/AndroidDrawableResizer and https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html but I'm wondering if they're all free to use without acknowledging the creator of the page?

And also, what's the difference between these two other than the second one having .9 in the png name?

Thanks

Comment: I know this one is free, has executable gui and works pretty well for me https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer

Comment: What image size should I input if my original copy is 512x512? xxhdpi? @CyberShark

Comment: I always put input as mspi is super low res and xxhdpi if decent. 
Here's another reference I found which is useful http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/